# Parsing Json to get all the contents in one NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsarray

That's the content...

```
[
    {
        "id": "",
        "title": "",
        "website": "",
        "categories": [
            {
                "id": "",
                "label": ""
            }
        ],
        "updated": 
    },
    {
        "id": "",
        "title": "",
        "website": "",
        "categories": [
            {
                "id": "",
                "label": ""
            }
        ],
        "updated": 
    }
]
```

How can I insert every feed source in one array?

```
 NSDictionary *results = [string JSONValue];
NSArray *subs = [results valueForKey:@"KEY"];
```

Which key I must insert?
THanks

Comment: You have an array of dictionaries.  You must iterate through the array somehow to extract the values from the dictionaries.  It's really quite simple, just look at the structure and understand that the code must match the structure.  Spend 5 minutes studying the JSON syntax at json.org so you will understand it.

Comment: You have, of course, edited the above JSON so that it's no longer valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as I can see your structure, you will get out of this JSON-String

```
NSArray:
[
    NSDictionary:
    {
        NSString: "id",
        NSString: "title",
        NSString: "website",
        NSArray:  "categories": 
        [
            NSDictionary:
            {
                NSString: "id",
                NSString: "label"
            }
        ],
        NSNumber: "updated"
    },
    NSDictionary:
    {
        ...
    }
]
```

So you have already an array of "Feeds" at root and you have to itterate them with their index in the array with. For first id i.e. `[[myJsonStructure objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"id"];`

Comment: It is also worth to mention, for newer compiler versions, the new syntax: *myJsonStructure[0][@"id"];*.